# Hide iframe content window scroll bar and use the window ( parent ) scroll bar instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe, scroll

this is my stack overflow question, hope whoever's reading the question understood the intent .I have a scenario where i am displaying the html from an api response and showing it in the content window of an iframe. The iframe has a padding of `0 100px`. I would like to remove the scroll bar from the content window , [Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQJpO.png)and show it on the main iframe. The iframe has 100% width and 100% height.
I am having a hard time resolving this problem.

Iframe styles are

```
height: 100%,
width: 100%,
border: none,
padding: 0 100px
```

The parent div styles

```
height: "584px",
display: "flex",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center",
flexDirection: "column",
overflow: "auto"
```

Here is the code to load the html

```
const writeHtml = () => {
const { html } = this.props;

const win = this.iframeRef.current?.contentWindow;
if (!win) {
   return;
 }
 const doc = win.document;
 doc.open();
 doc.write(_.unescape(html)); // to escape html entities like &;
 doc.close();
 }
```

This is the actual iframe

```
<iframe
   className={styles.iframe}
   ref={this.iframeRef}
   style={{
     display: loading ? "none" : "block"
   }}
 />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Disclaimer: already tried scrolling = "no" and overflow: hidden, also tried adding event onLoad and adding event listeners.  I am using a class based typescript components for my project.